# JQuery carousel сделать сдвиг на один элемент

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пишу функцию jQuery карусели на основе вот этого примера http://coolcodez.net/create-infinite-carousel-in-jquery-using-a-few-lines-of-code/
Вот мой код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.fn.carousel = function () {
    var carousel = $(this);
    var width = carousel.width();
    setInterval(function() {
        carousel.delay(1000).animate({
            right: '+=' + width
        }, 1000, function () {
            var first = carousel.find('>:first-child');
            first.remove();
            $(this).append(first);
            $(this).css({
                right: '-=' + width
            });
        });
    }, 2000);

    return $(this);
};

    $('#carousel-1').carousel();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8b65qbb/7/

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы сдвиг каждый раз был на один элемент, а не на три?

**upd**  
Вот пробую немного переписать код http://jsfiddle.net/n8b65qbb/9/, но всё равно не сдвигается так, как надо.